# Finding a tangent of an algebraic curve: $xy = 1$ [Well written explanation]

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find, using *(easy)* calculus, the slope of a tangent to the algebraic curve $xy = 1$.

- The tangent I want to find is the tangent that passes through the point $(x_i,y_i) = (0,f(t))$.
- $f$ is defined as $f(t) = 4\cdot2e^{-t/10}$.

I know the general way of finding the slope of a tangent to a function that passes through a point $P$ outside of the function is to put:

$$y-y_i = y'(x-x_i)$$

---

The problem for me is then to find $x_i$. I've tried the following:

Implicit differentiation of $xy=1$ gives me: 
$$y' = -\frac{y}{x}$$

I then attempt to use the general method of finding tangents that pass through a point.

- $y-0 = -\dfrac{y}{x}\left(x-4\cdot2^{t/10}\right) \iff 1 = -1+\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot4\cdot2^{t/10} \iff x=2\cdot2^{t/10}$

I'm not sure if I even chose the right approach. Any help appreciated, thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Implicit differentiation gives slope $-\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Whoops. Thank you; do you think I'm on my way to the correct answer?

Comment: Perhaps challenges are arising from the fact that $(0, f(t))$ cannot be on the curve $xy = 1$, since $0 \cdot f(t) = 0 \ne 1 = xy$?

Comment: Considering $f(t)$ can never reach $0$ on its own though, I don't see how it's a problem.

Comment: You may ge the right answer. There is a conceptual error that happens to give the right answer.

Comment: I found out my error. I'm looking for the point $(a,\frac{1}{a})$ (See $xy=1$). If I feel sure enough about my answer, I will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether we differentiate implicitly or explicitly. Explicit is not difficult in this case. We have $y=\frac{1}{x}$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Let $\left(a,\frac{1}{a}\right)$ be the point of tangency. The tangent line passes through  $(0,f(t))$ so it has slope
$$\frac{\frac{1}{a}-f(t)}{a-0}.$$
The tangent line has slope $-\frac{1}{a^2}$ and therefore
$$\frac{\frac{1}{a}-f(t)}{a-0}=-\frac{1}{a^2}.\tag{1}$$
We solve for $a$, by multiplying both sides by $a^2$. So we get $1-af(t)=-1$and therefore $a=\frac{2}{f(t)}$.

Now that we know the point of tangency, we can find the equation of the tangent line in the usual way.

**Remarks:** $1.$ Implicit differentiation makes things marginally simpler-looking. For that approach we would let the point of tangency be $(a,b)$. I think that for most students seeing these things for the first time, the approach we took is more natural.

$2.$ An alternative is to note that the tangent line at $(a,b)$ has equation
$$y-b=-\frac{1}{a^2}(x-a).$$
When $x=0$, we have $y=f(t)$. Substitute in the above equation, and note that $b=\frac{1}{a}$.  We can then solve for $a$ in terms of $f(t)$, and write down the equation of the tangent line.

$3.$ Note that we called the point of tangency $(a,1/a)$ or $(a,b)$. Calling it $(x,1/x)$ or $(x,y)$ is not a good idea, since we risk confusion with the $x,y$ in the equation of the tangent line.